# Hyperledger-fabric login and register a client to get the ORG_APIKEYs

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I want to get the ORG_APIKEYs to communicate with Hyperledger-fabric rest-API.I'm using this endpoint http://localhost:3000/api/assets/ for getting all assets in Hyperledger-fabric but I should give the headers X-Api-Key.

I want to get X-Api-Key using rest-API, How to do it?
please give any references